# Error retrieving saved image data using CoreData using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, firebase-storage

I have stored my class data for a class named "Cards" into core data. The "Cards" class included a field for images that stores image data. I seem to be able to successfully save the data to core data (no errors at least), but when attempting to access that data, I receive an unknown error.

Here is my save method to save each card to core data. It seems to be working fine.

```
func save(toBeSaved: Cards) {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CardEntity",
                                             in:managedContext)

    let card = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertInto: managedContext)

    //3
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.name, forKey: "name")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.imageName, forKey: "imageName")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.manaCost, forKey: "manaCost")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.rarity, forKey: "rarity")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.whichClass, forKey: "whichClass")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.cardType, forKey: "cardType")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.tribe, forKey: "tribe")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.cardText, forKey: "cardText")
    card.setValue(toBeSaved.set, forKey: "set")

    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        print("Feed: successfully saved")
        nsAllCards.append(card)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Here is the code that attempts to obtain the saved information out of core data.

```
// fetch cards and populate
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CardEntity")

    //3
    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        nsAllCards = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    print("Feed: core data contains \(nsAllCards.count) elements")

    if nsAllCards.count > 0 {
        for item in nsAllCards {
            print("Feed: \(item)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "name") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "imageName") as! Data)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "manaCost") as! Int)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "rarity") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "whichClass") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "cardType") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "tribe") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "cardText") as! String)")
            print("Feed: \(item.value(forKey: "set") as! String)")
            let tempCard = Cards(name: item.value(forKey: "name") as! String, imageName: item.value(forKey: "imageName") as! Data, manaCost: item.value(forKey: "manaCost") as! Int, rarity: item.value(forKey: "rarity") as! String, whichClass: item.value(forKey: "whichClass") as! String, cardType: item.value(forKey: "cardType") as! String, tribe: item.value(forKey: "tribe") as! String, cardText: item.value(forKey: "cardText") as! String, set: item.value(forKey: "set") as! String)
            allCards.append(tempCard)
        }
    }
```

I added all of those print lines in order to try to figure out where the error was, and it always gets stopped at the print imageName line (which holds Data for the image that was downloaded from firebase storage). 
As you may be able to tell from the code, after the print lines I am trying to construct an object using the data taken from core data so that instead of having an NSManagedObject I have a normal "Cards" object to use.

I am new to core data and am unsure if this is even the proper way to save an image that was downloaded from firebase storage. Please help in any way you can.

Code for my entity:

```
extension CardEntity {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CardEntity> {
    return NSFetchRequest<CardEntity>(entityName: "CardEntity");
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var imageName: NSData?
@NSManaged public var manaCost: Int16
@NSManaged public var rarity: String?
@NSManaged public var whichClass: String?
@NSManaged public var cardText: String?
@NSManaged public var tribe: String?
@NSManaged public var cardType: String?
@NSManaged public var set: String?
```

}

Comment: Log `toBeSaved` and `nsAllCards` to see what it contains. Show us the entity to see of which type `imageName` is. Also, you can use `nsAllCards = results as! [CardEntity]` and later `print("Feed: \(item.name)")`. Also `let card = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertInto: managedContext) as! CardEntity` and later `card.ame = toBeSaved.name`.

Comment: Is this a Firebase question as it includes that tag?

Comment: @Jay it's someone related, in case anyone knows a better way of storing the images from fire base.

Comment: @shallowThought I can't quite tell what you want me to do, I've already done most of that code

Comment: @TrevorJordy Sorry for the mess. The point was:  Log `toBeSaved` and `nsAllCards` to see what it contains and show us the entity to see of which type `imageName` is (in the Model).

Comment: @TrevorJordy the rest was only a tip. To use `[CardEntity]` instead of `[NSManagedObject]`. Independent of the issue.